# Binding a Command within a Datatemplate (XF/Prism)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Using Prism for Xamarin Forms, I have a ListView like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                   <Grid Margin="4" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Button Command="{Binding DoSomething}"/>
                    </Grid>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

where Conditions is an ObservableCollection of ConditionViewModel and the DoSomething command is located ***in the ViewModel of the Page.***

So, of course, the binding won't work here because it's bindingcontext is going to be an individual ConditionViewModel item.

I know that Relative bindings are not available in Xamarin and the prescribed solution appears to be to directly apply {x:Reference SomeViewModel}.  But using Prism, the View doesn't have direct access to its ViewModel, so this is not possible.

I've also looked at this, in an attempt to get a RelativeContext markup extension:
https://github.com/corradocavalli/Xamarin.Forms.Behaviors/blob/master/Xamarin.Behaviors/Extensions/RelativeContextExtension.cs
but, get an exception that the RootObject is null.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is something like this:

ViewModel:

```
public class MyPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MyPageViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new DelegateCommand<MyModel>( ExecuteMyCommand );
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Collection { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand<MyModel> MyCommand { get; }

    private void ExecuteMyCommand( MyModel model )
    {
        // Do Foo
    }
}
```

View;

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyProject.Views.MyPage"
             x:Name="page">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Button Command="{Binding BindingContext.MyCommand,Source={x:Reference page}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed.  Thank you thank you!

Comment: THANK YOU DAN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! YOUR A LIFESAVER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!